# Смена компилятора в CLion

Tags: c++, компилятор, настройки

Установил g++ через `brew install gcc` путь до него `/usr/local/bin/g++-7`, но CLion использует этот `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++` как можно сменить компилятор в настройках?

- ОС: macOS 10.12.6
- CLion: 2017.2

Comment: Попробуйте изменить используемый компилятор в CMake-файле Вашего проекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CMake файле:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang)
```

В настройках: Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/CMake

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang
```